# generate multiple files based on pattern

Tags: unix, awk

I have the following contents in a file

```
 0010CTCTLEDPPOO   STAND  201002971
 0010CTCTLEDPPOO   STAND  201002971
 0010CTCTLEDPPOO   STAND  201002971
 0010CTCTLEDPPOO   STAND  201002971
```

for every occurrence of `0010CTCTL`, `WNCRX` should be added the line before

```
WNCRX

0010CTCTLEDPPOO   STAND  201002971


WNCRX

0010CTCTLEDPPOO   STAND  201002971


WNCRX

0010CTCTLEDPPOO   STAND  201002971


WNCRX

0010CTCTLEDPPOO   STAND  201002971
```

I am using the following

```
awk '/0010CTCTL/{print "WNCRX"}1' file
```

i am able to achieve what is required, but i want each instance in a new file

so there should be four files each containing

```
WNCRX

0010CTCTLEDPPOO   STAND  201002971
```

can you please suggest how to generate individual files

Answer (score 1):

using your base:

- Use a redirection `>` to print into a file
- use a counter `++c` to increment the file name each line

cmd:

```
awk '/0010CTCTL/{file="file" ++c ".out";print "WNCRX" > file}{print > file}' file
```

Comment: Thank you,
I am able to generate multiple files but WNCRX is appending at start of the line like shown below

Comment: WNCRX     0010CTCTLEDPPOO; but i want in the below format

WNCRX
0010CTCTLEDPPOO

Comment: sorry, it is `print` and not `printf` to use, reply corrected

Comment: Thank you it worked, what need to done if we want output in single file rather than multiple files

Comment: remove `> file`  and redirect output at shell level, or remove the `" ++c "` to send to file.out directly

Comment: Than you, the output is generated in the bin folder; how to change the directory for the output files

Comment: just add the path in front of file name ex: `file="/MyPath/file.out"`

Comment: Thank you the script is working as required; once again thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You could postprocess the output from Awk with `csplit`.

```
awk '/0010CTCTL/{print "WNCRX"}1' file |
csplit - '/^WNCRX$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can try like this way also

```
while read line
do  
        File_Name=`date +%N`
        echo "WNCRX" >> ${File_Name}
        echo $line  >> ${File_Name}
    done < Src_FileName
```

So that you can make file name as dynamic values as per requirement.